# Based on datagridview check box other will disable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a [Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSxb2.png) :

Here when i check one client name's row, all other clients other than that client should be disabled. For example, if i check on 1st row, all client the rows other than having client name **Surbhi1 Texttile mills Pvt. Ltd.** should be disabled.

This is what i have tried:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
             int selected = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["clientid"].Value);
             bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["IsChecked"].Value);
             if (isSelected)
             {
                  if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["clientid"].Value) == selected)
                  {
                      dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
                  }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide me suggestions for this.

Comment: In your question, **if i check on 1st row, all client the rows other than having client name Surbhi1 Texttile mills Pvt. Ltd. should be disabled.** There are about 4 rows have the value your requested... is need to disable all the four?

Comment: should be disable other than **Surbhi1 Texttile mills Pvt. Ltd.*

Comment: whats the problem then?...Do you face any error?

Comment: With the code i have tried, all rows are getting disabled

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with my testdb, If you are using `datagrid`'s events, so you can use `datagrid`'s **cell event args**.

Here,

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Selected)
            {
                var clientItem = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["SirName"].Value.ToString();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (item.Cells["SirName"].Value.ToString() != clientItem)
                    {
                        item.Cells["SirName"].ReadOnly = true;
                        item.Cells["SirName"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

and the output was; 
[image]

So in your situation the code should be;

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IsChecked"].Selected)
                {
                    var clientItem = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["clientid"].Value.ToString();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (item.Cells["clientid"].Value.ToString() != clientItem)
                        {
                            item.Cells["clientid"].ReadOnly = true;
                            item.Cells["clientid"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
```

Hope helps,(Has given `backcolor` to show better, you can delete.)